# Running into MySQL column width limits on localhost but not on AWS server

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have a MySQL table with 650 columns and 1 row.  **I know this is a bad design** (which I inherited) and it WILL be moved to a simple two-column layout, but at the moment I'm trying to diagnose a different problem to be able to understand it.  **I don't want to fix the design issues if it will mask the system configuration issue I'm currently facing.**

Background: I have a system which takes the following steps in building an instance of a web application:

1. Use a skeleton.sql file to build the "version 0" of the database.
2. Run an upgrade.sh script which looks through an "upgrades" directory and...
3. ...runs each of those upgrade files to change the database structure (including adding new columns to the already-too-wide table), in proper order.

The issue is, on my localhost server (WAMP) while running one of the scripts in step 3, I'm getting an error when attempting to add more columns to that table:

`Row size too large. The maximum row size for the used table type, not counting BLOBs, is 8126.`

Again, I know the table is too "wide" in theory, but I don't know any query I can run to calculate how wide it is.  Further, I'm not getting this error on my RDS server when I run this, and since I don't know how to get the "width" of the table I don't know how to compare (though given localhost's VARCHARs are populated with FEWER characters, I expect it to be smaller regardless).

Everything I'm reading on StackOverflow says that all tables have the same "width" limit, regardless of engine.  I suspect it's a configuration issue, but if this is a hard limit, **why is it working on my RDS server but not localhost?**

Answer (score 0):

My only thought was character code differences? Have you looked into that? (Sorry can't comment too new a user).

Comment: What do you mean by character code differences?  They're both using `UTF-8`, and the skeleton.sql files are from the same code repository; they are identical.

Comment: That was my answer -- UTF8 would require more space than ANSI/ASCII.